# Fazer uma pergunta melhor que foi fechada

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas

Abri outra discussão aqui que falava sobre fechar uma pergunta claramente postada de forma ruim. Algumas pessoas falaram que a pergunta é interessante. Acho que na verdade estavam querendo dizer que o assunto é interessante. Uma pergunta ruim é ruim, deveria ser fechada e dependendo do caso até negativada. Se positivar porque o assunto é legal, curioso, interessante, útil, mas a pergunta for uma bomba eu acho que está errado.

Pois bem, se o assunto é interessante e a pergunta é ruim, **por que ninguém tenta melhorar a pergunta?**

Ok, alguns não gostam de mexer no conteúdo do autor. Eu acho que tem casos que é melhor que deixar lá morto, desde que não mude a intenção do autor. Mas se não dá para mexer na pergunta para salvá-la, **por que não fazem uma pergunta nova melhor que aquela já que o assunto é bom?**

Comment: Preguiça(ao menos é meu caso nas poucas vezes que me deparei com essa situação),

Answer (score 5):

Eu concordo com a ideia de abrir novas perguntas que são versões saudáveis das perguntas ruins fechadas. Acho inclusive que seria uma boa linkar as perguntas originais, para que se possa fazer uma comparação entre uma forma ruim e uma forma boa de se fazer uma pergunta. Muitas vezes pares de exemplos do tipo **errado - certo** tornam manuais e seções de ajuda mais claros e didáticos.

Sobre as perguntas ruins. Eu tento resgatar algumas de vez em quando. Ajustes de tags, remoção de código irrelevante, correção ortográfica, indentação etc. Em alguns casos isso é suficiente.

Sobre a categoria de perguntas que são interessantes, porém que deveriam ser fechadas... Acredito que as últimas que vi pecavam principalmente por não terem incluso as tentativas do autor para resolver o problema. Mas ao menos nos dois ou três casos mais recentes que me chamaram a atenção, acho que os autores talvez não tenham colocado o que tentaram porque *não sabiam nem por onde começar*.

---

[Em um caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223592/1658), a solução era simples - o AP queria copiar um trecho de uma imagem para outra com .NET. O exemplo de como fazer isso é trivial. São poucas linhas de código, quase que dá pra escrever na mão de caneta. Muitos novatos têm essa dúvida, então achei que a pergunta era boa pro site - ela ajudaria muito mais pessoas do que perguntas do tipo *"encontre o erro no meu código"* que nós vemos todos os dias. **O que mata a pergunta é que o AP poderia ter resolvido o próprio problema com alguns minutos de pesquisa ou tentativa e erro.**

Já [outro caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219078/1658) que eu vi foi mais complexo. O AP queria escrever um arquivo de Excel, sem precisar do Excel instalado. Isso não é trivial. O formato do arquivo é um pequeno inferno. A API oficial para isso, além de confusa e mal documentada, não é muito conhecida - no sentido de que não é algo que você reconhece pelo nome como jQuery, Swing, Hibernate etc. Existem tantas formas de se cometer erros que cada pessoa que for usar a API terá os seus próprios problemas, que muitas vezes não serão nem reproduzíveis por outras pessoas. Para completar, muitos dos exemplos que se acham na Internet estão cheios de gambiarras e piores práticas. Como muita gente tem a necessidade de escrever planilhas programaticamente, achei que dar um exemplo mínimo, que pudesse servir de de resposta canônica, poderia ser útil... Mas nesse caso, **o que mata a pergunta é que ela não parecia possuir nenhuma tentativa de resolver o problema - parecia mesmo algo do tipo "resolvam meu problema por favor"**.

---

Eu coloquei os exemplos acima por dois motivos:

- Acho que podem ser um estudo de caso. Podemos fazer um *post mortem* dessas perguntas para criar novas versões delas que sejam úteis para o site (caso seja possível - não descarto a hipótese de simplesmente não haver forma fazer isso).
- Eu mesmo não sei como melhorá-las. Tentei escrever versões melhores, mas vi que eu mesmo as fecharia pelos mesmos motivos que marquei em negrito nos parágrafos acima. Mas no meu caso é porque eu realmente não sei perguntar (acho que 95% da minha reputação vem de respostas, não de perguntas). Eu gostaria de ver como seriam possíveis versões melhoradas delas, para que eu possa usar para calibrar as minhas próprias perguntas.

Comment: Eu não consigo ver isso como uma solução do problema. É claro q uma pergunta mal elaborada se for feito por alguém q sabe como perguntar vai trazer um beneficio para a comunidade, más, pode fazer com que o autor original da pergunta, fique mais preguiçoso em relação a criação de novas perguntas, a uma chance disso acontecer. Eu prefiro oferecer uma recompensa para usuários novos caso ele faça uma pergunta canônica e com um problema reproduzível ou bem contextualizado.